# Control inside control with Winforms

Tags: .net, winforms

Is it possible to put a combo box inside a list box? I'd like to create a list (inside the list box) with each entry having a combo box next to it.

Comment: WPF works best for doing things like this.

Comment: So what I want is possible with WPF?

Comment: XAML markup used in WPF naturally supports Templates for controls so nesting is very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Instead, you should use a DataGridView with a ComboBox column.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution for you since it's already implemented in a DataGridView - but to answer your question, yes, it is possible.

If the listbox is named ListBox1 and the ComboBox is named ComboBox1:

```
ListBox1.Controls.Add(ComboBox1)
```

You can add new comboboxes and position them just like in a panel.